# How to integrate mlflow with tensorflow object detection api

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api, mlflow

I am trying to use the **mlflow.tensorflow.autolog()** with [tensorflow object detection api](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). Adding **mlflow.tensorflow.autolog()** to **[model_main.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main.py)** logs some parameters like global_norm/clipped_gradient_norm,global_norm/gradient_norm,global_step/sec,learning_rate_1,loss_1,loss_2 in mlflow. However the more important metrics like map,precision,recall are not being logged in mlfow.

Comment: Are those metrics available as part of the trained model object or some other object in the TF object detection API?  Or do you have to calculate them by hand?

Answer (score 1):

The mlflow autologging will log whatever metrics are specified for the keras model, e.g. as in https://keras.io/metrics/ and https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/examples/keras/train.py#L66. Are those metrics specified but not logged?

Comment: I am using tf estimator and not keras . I updated my question with links to the code [model_main.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main.py).Please have  a look